# Connect to Hidden network using wpa_supplicant

Tags: wifi

I have router [ssid: wifi_team, pwd: delhi123 and security type: wpa2] as hidden access point and other end wpa_supplicant is running from comand line. I am trying to connect to my router, while connecting it is asking only ssid and psk if I entered correct inputs the connection is successful. But I want to enter security type of hidden network while connecting. Is anyone know how to enter security type?